# grails get hasmany object

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have two domain classes

```
class A {
...
static hasMany= [b:B]
}
class B {
...
static belongsTo=[a:A]
}
```

When I try to get `a.b` , I get a list of `b`, e.g. `[1,2,3]`

When I create a `new B();`, then try to get `a.b`, I get `[1,2,3]` 
but `[1,2,3,4]` is expected. 
I think this result comes from cache.

When I use

```
a.refresh() 
a.b
```

then, the expected result comes fine, e.g. `[1,2,3,4]`

My question is: How can I get the expected result [1,2,3,4] by querying `a.b` without using the `refresh()` method?

another problem is ..

```
 assuming
```

`b.somefield = c`

when query `a.b.somefiled`
result is [a,b,c]

if i update b.somefiled = d

when i try `a.b.somefiled`
result is [a,b,c]
expected result is [a,b,d]

I use the database mongodb.

Comment: Are you using a.addToB or just saving a new B?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you aren't following standard procedure and adding your B to your A using the addTo method for the collection. Here is an example of what you should be doing when you create a new B.

```
B newB = new B()
A existingA = A.get(1)
existingA.addToB(newB)
existingA.save()
```

The above will both save A and B as well as ensure that B is inside the collection of Bs on the given A within Hibernate's second level cache.

Also, you can fine tune the hibernate cache settings for your domain and collections off of that domain. The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/cache.html) explains this in great detail.

Comment: when a try existingA.addToB(newB) geting error No signature of method:

Comment: I'm sorry? I don't understand. :/

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. If the answer helped you solve the problem then please accept it as a valid answer.

Comment: i got another issue with is, i updated the question should i try again  existingA.addToB(newB)
existingA.save() on update of newB can you please see that

Comment: It's unclear about how you are sequencing the updates and such. Also, this is a new question and should be posted as a new question. When you do post, try and post as much of your relevant code as possible That will ensure that people can see what's going on and assist you further.